# Parsing url html with lxml failed loading foreign entity

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I'm trying to parse through the emojis in the url provided.  It's a tutorial in Data Wrangling Book to help me understand data analysis.  This is a verbatim code from the text book and gives me the error at the end.  I have heard suggestions for using urllib2 but the point of this exercise is to use lxml.  Is this achievable, or is this example just outdated?  Can you provide some insight to get this to run, parse the emojis, and then return the list.

```
from lxml import html

page = html.parse('http://www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/')

proper_headers = page.xpath('//h2|//h3')
proper_lists = page.xpath('//ul')

all_emoji = []

for header, list_cont in zip(proper_headers, proper_lists):
    section = header.text
    for li in list_cont.getchildren():
        emoji_dict = {}
        spans = li.xpath('div/span')
        if len(spans):
            link = spans[0].get('data-src')
            if link:
                emoji_dict['emoji_link'] = li.base_url + link
            else:
                emoji_dict['emoji_link'] = None
            emoji_dict['emoji_handle'] = spans[1].text_content()
        else:
            emoji_dict['emoji_link'] = None
            emoji_dict['emoji_handle'] = li.xpath('div')[0].text_content()
        emoji_dict['section'] = section
        all_emoji.append(emoji_dict)

print all_emoji
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chp11-scraping/lxml_emoji_xpath.py", line 24, in <module>
    page = html.parse('http://www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/')
  File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 940, in parse
    return etree.parse(filename_or_url, parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3426, in lxml.etree.parse
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1840, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1866, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1770, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1163, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 601, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 711, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 638, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
IOError: Error reading file 'http://www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/': failed to load external entity "http://www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

it redirect to `https` and lxml not supported, use `urllib2` or `requests` to read the html

```
from lxml import html
import urllib2

# https://www.webpagefx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/
doc = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/')
page = html.parse(doc)
```